# Ramanujan type functional equations

Tags: calculus

using mellin transform I try to determinate R(x) if it is possible(and if exits) a functional equation of the following 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -\frac{k  e^{k x}}{\left(e^{k x}-1\right)^2}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } R (k x)+\frac{x}{24}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6 x}-\frac{\log (x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )$$
the transform I using is $$\zeta (s) \zeta (s-1) \Gamma (s)$$
Could you find it?

Comment: The Mellin transform of the left is $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s-1)^2$ which does not produce a functional equation but an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: hi Marco you are wright but anyway could you calculate R[k x] thanks

Comment: anyway working in this series i get of R(n x)=$$-\frac{2 \pi ^2 n}{x}+\log \left(\frac{4 \pi ^2 n}{x}\right)-\log \left(\frac{2 \pi ^2 n \text{csch}\left(\frac{2 \pi ^2 n}{x}\right)}{x}\right)$$